# How to output hidden_field to array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Working on a reply function for basic messaging app, and have been stuck for a while.

In my message controller I'm passing the user_id from the original message author to :to for the reply message":

```
    @message = current_user.sent_messages.build(:to => @original.author.id, :subject => subject, :body => body)
    render :template => "sent/raply"
```

My hidden field looks like:

```
    <%= f.hidden_field :to %>
```

I'm getting the correct user_id passing through the form, but I need the value to be passed as an array like "to"=>["1"], instead of "to"=>"1".

Comment: Can't you just change it to an array in the controller?

Comment: Setting `:to => [@original.author.id]` sends an array to the form, but as currently constituted the form outputs the array as a string. I need to go from controller (as string/int) -> form (output on send as an array with the value passed from the controller as :to inside, i.e. `:to => ["user_id"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Kept the controller as such:

```
@message = current_user.sent_messages.build(:to => @original.author.id, :subject => subject, :body => body)
render :template => "sent/raply"
```

Updated my form field:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :to, :multiple => true %>
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

```
@message = current_user.sent_messages.build(:to => [@original.author.id], :subject => subject, :body => body)
render :template => "sent/raply"
```

Comment: Hey Brad, that's what I tried first but that sends `"[user_id]"` to params - what I need is `["user_id"]`. Any other ideas?